# Accessing Another View Controller IBOutlet from App Delegate

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have a tab bar app.  One of the controllers is a "preference page".  What I am trying to do accomplish is access the uiswitch ivar that is on the "preference page" controller from the app delegate's applicationWillTerminate method, however I am only getting the default IUSwitch value.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
  SettingsController *settings = [[SettingsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsView" bundle:nil]];
  NSLog(@"settings preference value: %d", [settings isOn]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wont work because your are essentially creating another instance new of SettingsController which of course will not include a reference to the settings ivar in the original SettingsController.  What you need to do is save a reference to the original SettingdController somewhere, either in the app delegate or in a singleton object.

[Here's a good blog](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) on wether to use the app delegate or singleton method to pass around global references.  I would personally use the singleton method.

Comment: you are exactly right. (forgot to mention that I recognized that my current methodology was flawed).  Is there a straight forward way to accomplish what I am doing or should I go down another path?

Comment: see the link I provided in the answer for ways of dealing with this.